# Unable to plot geotiff on Leaflet-geotiff

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am trying to plot my geotiff NDVI data on to leaflet as a heatmap; but I am unable to render the data.Nothing seems to be gettting displayed. My geotiff is in EPSG:4326 - this is the geotiff; I am trying with two-

https://brian-transcription-test.s3.amazonaws.com/RGB_masked.tif

and my code is something like this-

````
  const map = L.map('devTestingDemo').setView([ 18.5286120,73.9715862], 30);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 10,
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map);

  const windSpeed = LeafletGeotiff.leafletGeotiff(
    'https://brian-transcription-test.s3.amazonaws.com/NDVINew4.tiff',
    {
      band: 0,
      name: 'Wind speed',
      renderer: new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.Plotty({
        displayMin: 0,
        displayMax: 30,
        arrowSize: 20,
        clampLow: false,
        clampHigh: true,
        colorScale: 'rainbow'
      })
    }
  ).addTo(map);

  const windDirection = LeafletGeotiff.leafletGeotiff(
    'https://brian-transcription-test.s3.amazonaws.com/NDVINew4.tiff',
    {
      band: 0,
      name: 'Wind direction',
      renderer: new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.VectorArrows({
        arrowSize: 20,
        displayMin: 0,
        displayMax: 6,
      })
    }
  ).addTo(map);
}```
````

Comment: Your tiff files are huge (400+mb) maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @kboul I have tried using a smaller file (approx 700 kb)  - the one provided on top - https://brian-transcription-test.s3.amazonaws.com/RGB_masked.tif but still no result

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing LeafletGeotiff to L.  For example:

```
const windSpeed = L.leafletGeotiff(
    'https://brian-transcription-test.s3.amazonaws.com/NDVINew4.tiff',
    {
      band: 0,
      name: 'Wind speed',
      renderer: new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.Plotty({
        displayMin: 0,
        displayMax: 30,
        arrowSize: 20,
        clampLow: false,
        clampHigh: true,
       colorScale: 'rainbow'
    })
  }
).addTo(map);
```

I am unsure about this part "new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.Plotty" you will need to experiment.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue as it worked for the authors example as the code is used from there; the problem is most likely with the tiff but not sure what. Im following the provided epsg of 4326. The tiff the author is using is -https://stuartmatthews.github.io/leaflet-geotiff/tif/wind_direction.tif. I have also tried with a tif instead of a tiff file; still no result.@zakariah1